# Alternative to ACTION_SHUTDOWN on Android API 28

Tags: android

I am writing an Android app and need to performe some code before phone switches off. Previously, this was possible by defining a BroadcastReceiver and registering it in `AndroidManifest.xml` with:

```
<receiver android:name="MyBroadcastReceiver" >
    <intent-filter> 
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

In this case, before phone is switched off, an intent with action ACTION_SHUTDOWN is sent to MyBroadcastReceiver and the code in the methode onReceive is executed.

But this is not working anymore in API 28 because `ACTION_SHUTDOWN` cannot be registered in the manifest anymore.

I tried to register a `BroadcastReceiver` with `ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED` (because it is still allowed) that triggers on boot a service whose task is to monitor and detect when the phone is shut down, but it didn't work.

Comment: You can register the listener at runtime in your application class, if it needs to run only if your app is actually running.

Comment: No, it has to run in the background even if the user did not open the app.